# Is there a way to find holomorphy or path independence without using Cauchy's or Morera's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

According to Cauchy's integral theorem, a holomorphic function in a simply connected domain is path independent. According to Morera's theorem, a path independent and continuous function is holomorphic. In other words, each one implies the other.

But that begs the question, is there a way, some theorem, to find either easily? In the real set, the curl operator can be used to find path independence, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a differentiable complex function $f$ of a complex variable is holomorphic if and only if the [Cauchy-Riemann](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) equations hold. Those are totally analogous to the vanishing of curl.

Comment: Wait, it's a double implication? I thought that the CR equations were necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: Yes, they are sufficient, because they mean that the differential form $fdz$ is closed (it has exterior derivative 0). By Stokes theorem, this implies the integral of $fdz$ is path-independent. If you don't know Stokes theorem, it's just like Green's theorem.

Comment: Maybe I should add that holomorphy is a local property, so that's why locally, path independency and closedness are equivalent

Comment: @agaminon Incidentally, the statement in this answer can be strengthened even further. See [the Looman-Menchoff Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem)